# API Client 1.3 (rev89) - Error 500 "No individual errors" when using Fields Filter

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Today (10.00 AM GMT+2) the code deployed in a production environment, started throwing an increasing number of errors while requesting file lists from a Google Drive folder, the error was always 500 "No Individual Errors".

After 2 hours, all the request failed.

The code regarding the file list request is the following:

```
'Search for a specific file name
oListReq.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = '" + ParentFolder + "' and trashed=false"
oListReq.Fields = "items/id" 'MSO - 20130621 - only ID is needed
oListReq.MaxResults = 10 'Max 10 files (too many I Expect only 1)

'Get the results
oFileList = oListReq.Fetch()
```

Testing the same requests with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) there is no problem and only the ID is returned.

Going step by step trying to identify the problem, turns out that all the requests with the Fields field specified generated a 500 error (other requests in the code have "items(id,alternateLink)" but the result is the same as the code above).

Temporary fixed the code commenting those lines.

Could you please investigate why this filters are not working with the .Net Client Library anymore?

Comment: A problem for our end too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that. This error has been reproduced and Google is investigating on this. For now, please turn off fields filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is now fixed. We had the same issue with one of our production application, we had to produce a hot fix, but I performed a test a few minutes ago and it looks like it works again.

Comment: Going to wait for an Official response before pushing the "undo fix", but thanks for the news